# Can the word "help" be used as the example sentence below

Tags: spoken-english

Does "thanks for making me feel like it's a help" make sense ?

Comment: Can you explain in what context?

Answer (score -1):

It does not sound correct to me. try

**"thanks for making me feel like it's been a help"** if the help has already been received.

"**thanks for making me feel like it's helping**" if the situation is on going